# How to frame a join query for the following situation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table structures:

```
 Item:
 -----------------------
 item_id INT (PRIMARY),
 category_id MEDIUMINT,
 name VARCHAR(40)

 reservation:
 -----------------------
 id INT (PRIMARY),
 item_id INT,
 date DATE,
 slot VARCHAR(50)
```

i want all rows of a particular category_id from table Item  with a join to reservation table ON column item_id WHERE reservation.date = 'something' to be returned in a query. There is no guarantee that reservation row will be available with the queried date. But i need all the rows of corresponding category_id to be returned from Item table even if reservation row is absent. How can this be achived?

regards,
ravi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a `left join` would fit the bill.  If you add the date restriction to the `on` clause, the date restriction will not filter out rows from `Item`.

```
select  *
from    Item i
left join
        reservation r
on      i.item_id = r.item_id
        and r.date = '2012-06-11'
where   category_id = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join. For example using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/728fe/2) I came up with:

```
select *
from item as i
left join reservation as r
  on i.item_id = r.item_id and r.date is not null (where reservation date is set or use r.date = 'date' if you want a specific date)
where i.category_id = '1'
```